# no module found pyodbc in aws lambda for python mssql connection

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pyodbc

AWS Lambda is showing me 'no module import error' for package pyodbc in my lambda function.
I've been using another library without error like this only getting error for this 'pyodbc' lib. 
I've added pyodbc installing with pip to my python code directory and upload 
them in zip to aws lambda.

Comment: Please provide more information about how you created your zip file. I assume you saw the official [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)?

Comment: yea i have downloaded pyodbc library with **pip install -t. pyodbc** to current lambda function directory and made zip of then and uploaded to aws lambda.

Comment: i think that the pyodbc need to be installed in linux environment using pip then i would work !!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to ensure that the native libraries that pyodbc requires are present in the Lambda execution environment - either bundled as part of your deployment package or as a separate Lambda layer.

See https://medium.com/@narayan.anurag/breaking-the-ice-between-aws-lambda-pyodbc-6f53d5e2bd26 for more details about this.